# Visitors Visa Refused based on incorrect information

Tags: visas, uk, ghanaian-citizens

I applied for a visitors visa last year in December. I got a response yesterday indicating that my application had been refused. On reading the reasons why it was refused, I was stunned. 
1. The decision maker said that I had stated I earn GHC 800/year. The is not true. I had specifically mentioned in my application that I earn GHC 800/month. I there believe that due to not reading the application properly, my visa was refused.

> *The decision
>
> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the  requirements of
>   paragraph(s) V4.2 of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for visitors
>   because:  In order to be able to make a decision on whether or not to
>   grant you entry clearance in this  category I have taken into account
>   your stated circumstances in Ghana, the reasons for your  visit and
>   your proposed travel arrangements. You stated in your Visa Application
>   Form that  you are coming for 13 days to visit family. I understand
>   that family visits are important and I  have therefore carefully
>   considered all of the elements of your application, weighing the 
>   importance of your proposed visit against the requirements of the
>   Immigration Rules.   I note that you have previously been refused
>   entry clearance for the UK. However each  application is considered on
>   its own merits.  In your application you state that you are employed
>   as Office Administrator earning a yearly  income of 800 GHS (£128.951
>   at exchange rate £1 = 6.20391). However from the  documents submitted
>   in your application I am not satisfied as to your declared employment 
>   in terms of regularity and income. The transaction history in the copy
>   of your bank statement  you have provided does not reflect the income
>   you have quoted, and indicates large sums of  deposits made to your
>   account for which you have provided no explanation.  Furthermore, you
>   state that you have no dependants, and the documents you have provided
>   do not show your family or social circumstances in Ghana.  You have
>   not shown any  property or assets in Ghana. You also state that you
>   have not travelled outside your country  of residence in the last 10
>   years, and you have had no history of travel to countries directly 
>   comparable to the United Kingdom or shown travel and compliance with
>   immigration  procedures similar to those of the United Kingdom. I am
>   therefore not satisfied that your  circumstances in Ghana, coupled
>   with your reasons for wishing to travel to the UK, are such  that you
>   have shown that your intentions are as stated or that you intend to
>   leave the UK at  the end of your proposed visit.  This means that, on
>   the evidence before me, and the balance of probabilities, I am not 
>   satisfied that you have accurately presented your circumstances or
>   intentions in wishing to  enter the UK.  I am not satisfied that you
>   intend to leave the UK at the end of your visit, that  you will not
>   live in the UK through frequent or successive visits, that you are
>   genuinely  seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted by the
>   visitor routes. This means that your  application for a visit visa has
>   been refused under paragraph V4.2 (a) (c) of the Immigration  Rules*

The email also mentioned that:

> In relation to this decision, there is no right of appeal or right to administrative review.

However, it is obvious that my application was not properly looked at and hence the wrong decison was given. How can I appeal?

Comment: Before trying to appeal, you will also need to have a solid explanation for "large sums of deposits made to your account for which you have provided no explanation".  (Unless this is your monthly salary, that is!)

Comment: Another strange thing is the reply states that you have not proved you have no dependants in Ghana. How would anyone do that?

Comment: @WeatherVane no, it doesn't.  The reply notes that the OP has *stated* that (s)he has no dependents, and that the supporting documentation gives no picture of his/her family and social circumstances.  No proof is required of the former claim, as it's a claim against advantage; having no dependants in your source country is a red flag.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's the other way around: they did not demonstrate that they *do* have dependents, which would increase the odds of them returning.

Comment: Don't get tunnel-vision over the month/year typo, since that's probably all it was. Your stated income is just the "tip of the iceberg" in the ECO's decision to refuse your application. You need to address *all* of the reasons for the refusal.

Answer (score 4):

That could be a typo by the ECO, ie per year instead of per month. Even if it’s not, I can tell you with a good degree of confidence that your correct salary of 800 GHS (£128.951) per month is not going to change the ECO’s decision.

Finally the other point about unexplained deposits is in itself enough evidence for a visa refusal.

In summary I don’t think it’s worth chasing an appeal/review.

Answer (score -1):

you have no right to appeal, that doesn't mean you can't contact the embassy and ask them very politely to review your refusal as you believe it was made in error (and mention the reason you think so).

Whether the embassy will consider that letter or not is where you have no rights, they may just throw it in the bin and you'd have no legal recourse, or they may investigate and refuse you anyway, or they investigate and send you a visa with an apology for the trouble, anything could happen.

But whatever you do, be polite and courteous.